# Calculate metric length in LaTeX (e.g. for TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths

I would like to calculate the length of elements on a LaTeX beamer frame (128mm*96mm) equivalent to those on a PowerPoint slide (254mm*190.5mm), i.e. apply the factor 128/254 to a value given in mm.

Therefor I would like to implement a function `\def\pptsize #1{#1/254*128}` which then can be used for instance in TikZ point definitions like `\draw (0,0) -- (0,\pptsize{10cm});`. Any ideas how to do so?

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=128/254] ...`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xfp`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\pptsize}{m}{\fpeval{#1*128/254}pt}

\begin{document}

\pptsize{10cm}

\end{document}
```

This prints

> 143.3839667679335pt

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rescale all coordinates in a `tikzpicture`, you can just use `scale`. Since you seem to be loading `tikz` you can use its commands to convert lengths, i.e. there is no need to load extra packages, but you really do not have to do that by hand.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Convert coordinates $\to$ use scale}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=128/254]
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

10cm get converted to
\pgfmathparse{10*128/254}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}cm
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works and might be the easier solution in my case. Unfortunately (but pretty obvious), this changes `\pageheight` and `\pagewidht` which I therefore "restore" using `\def\w{\paperwidth*1.984375}`.
Interestingly, the scaling does not work for the included image in `\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=3.94cm]{logo.pdf}}` where I have to use `width=1.9855cm` instead...

Comment: @F1iX AFAIK this does not change `\paperheight` and `\pagewidth`. If you add `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=128/254,nodes={transform shape}]`, the nodes will be transformed, i.e. scaled, as well.

Comment: thanks for the hint, `nodes={transform shape}` works for scaling the image! Indeed it does not "change" `\paperheight`, but scales it, so the line `\draw (0,0) -- (\paperwidth, \paperheight)` covers only part of the slide.

Comment: @F1iX Yes, of course. If you use `\tikx[remember picture,overlay]{\draw (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east);}` you'll get a diagonal regardless of the scaling you may want to add.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! Yet another issue: `\draw[line widht=4pt]` does not get scaled either :D

Comment: @F1iX No, it doesn't. It is, however, rather straightforward to fix this. All you need to do is to use `\pgfgettransformentries` to read out the scale factors from the transformation matrix and apply it/them. I guess that the reason why there is no automatic solution in the pgfmanual nor in the standard libraries is that in general it is not well-defined how to scale the line width if you have, say, `xscale=1,yscale=0.5`. As I said, for universal scaling one can write a style that does that.